# How to split string into two arrays in Lua?

Tags: string, lua

I am using Lua and i have a file that i want to split each line into two different arrays. Each line of my file contains two string seperated with a space.
for example if my file contains

```
 something something_else
```

I should have

```
tab_1[1] = something
tab_2[1] = something_else
```

I tried using split like

```
file =io.open("myfile.txt", "r")
for line in file:lines() do
line = file:read()
for value in split(line," ")
table.insert(tab_1,value[i])
table.insert(tab_2,value[i])
i=i+1
end
```

it seems to be wrong as i know split probably does not return an array but i know that it return different string . How can i manage them .

Comment: `tab_1[1]` and `tab_2[2]`? That seems a bit strange. Also, from your code it seems more like you want `tab_1[1]` and `tab_2[1]`.

Comment: yes i was wrong about that ouuups it is tab_1[1] and tab_2[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in io.lines'myfile.txt' do
  local v1, v2 = line:match'(.-)%s+(.*)'
  table.insert(tab_1,v1)
  table.insert(tab_2,v2)
end
```

Comment: actually that did not work as expected actually i don't know if i was clear enough but my file contains urls and ip addresses separated by a space it is not just simple words . The second variable v2 does not get any value

Comment: Please show an example of string from your text file where `v2` gets no value with my code.

Comment: i couldnt put the http url as it is because it will be a link

Comment: Works [fine](https://eval.in/38357) for me.  Test it with another lines and give a link where the problem is.

Comment: your code is just fine @Egor it was something wrong with my code and i fix it , thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in io.lines('myfile.txt') do
  local v1, v2 = string.match(line, "^(%S+)%s+(%S+)$")
  if v1 and v2 then
    table.insert(tab_1,v1)
    table.insert(tab_2,v2)
  else
    -- wrong line
  end
end
```